# Need to access the API to share folder with variable lists of people

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working in VB 2010 to create some data acquisition programs and one of the requests is that we use Google Drive to store and share the Excel files once created. I have been able to save and sync folders into My Drive, I now need to be able to share this folder with a variable list of email addresses.

The emails would all be "name"@mix.wvu.edu and they would be inputing those at the beginning of the experiment so that when they save it will automatically be sent to My Drive and then emailed to the students.

Basically, I need some help writing code to select a folder of files from My Drive, click "share", add people that have the ability to edit the files and send them upon the student clicking the button below.  Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

- [sample code of what I have so far as a .xlsx file](https://docs.google.com/a/mix.wvu.edu/file/d/0B_YscePF1YjgRlZxaXltQUhBQnM/edit?usp=sharing)

#### Sample data set

```
                            Tension Test
Date:               Apr-06-2013             Load    Extension       Stress  Strain
Time:               15:07                   6       4.5
Specimen Material:  Plexiglass              7       6
Specimen #:         14                      8       7.5
Width:              34                      9       9
Thickness:          3                       10      10.5
Area:               102                     11      12
Gage Length:        3                       12      13.5
Data Rate:          10                      13      15
                                            14      16.5
                                            15      18
                                            16      19.5
                                            17      21
                                            18      22.5
                                            19      24
                                            20      25.5
                                            21      27
                                            22      28.5
                                            23      30
                                            24      31.5
                                            25      33
```

Answer (score 0):

For sharing files, please see: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing and the permissions resource: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions

If you have any specific questions, please ask them.